# How to load Django JSON to avoid conflicts with natural keys

Tags: python, django, json

I have a JSON file sample.json:

```
[
    {
        "pk": null, 
        "model": "auth.user", 
        "fields": {
            "username": "JoeBob"
        }
    }
]
```

I already have an auth.User model with the username `JoeBob`.

If I load this into a Django app via `manage.py loaddata sample.json`, I would expect it to create the record if it doesn't exist, or otherwise do nothing. In this case, it should do nothing.

However, it appears to try and create a duplicate record, returning the error:

```
IntegrityError: Could not load auth.User(pk=None): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=(JoeBob) already exists.
```

How do I load JSON data so that it only creates records where the corresponding natural key does not already exist? Supposedly, Django's auth.User model [does support natural keys](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13914).

Answer (score 1):

The `loaddata` management command is not intended for adding data to an existing database--it's intended to be used for loading fixtures for testing or bootstrapping purposes ([see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture))--and thus does not play nicely with existing data.

If you want to load data from JSON to update or augment your user list, you'll be much better off [writing a custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) that implements the semantics you want.

You can see the answers to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940294/import-data-into-django-model-with-existing-data) for more ideas of how to proceed.